# wait doesn't wait for the processes in the while loop to finish

Tags: bash

Here is my code:

```
count=0
head -n 10 urls.txt | while read LINE; do
        curl -o /dev/null -s "$LINE" -w "%{time_total}\n" &
    count=$((count+1))
    [ 0 -eq $((count % 3)) ] && wait && echo "process wait" # wait for 3 urls
done
echo "before wait"
wait
echo "after wait"
```

I am expecting the last curl to finish before printing the last echo, but actually it's not the case:

```
0.595499
0.602349
0.618237
process wait
0.084970
0.084243
0.099969
process wait
0.067999
0.068253
0.081602
process wait
before wait
after wait
➜  Downloads 0.088755 # already exited the script
```

Does anyone know why it's happening? And how to fix this?

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 . (It's taking about shell variables rather than `wait`, but the cause and solution are the same.)

Answer (score 3):

As described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024), this is caused by your pipeline causing the `while` loop to be performed in a different shell from the rest of your script.

Consequently, your `curl`s are subprocesses of that subshell, not the outer interpreter; so the outer interpreter cannot `wait` for them.

This can be resolved by not piping to `while read`, but instead redirecting its input in a way that doesn't shuffle it into a pipeline element -- as with `<(...)`, a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ - NOT /bin/sh; also, must not start with "sh scriptname"

count=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    curl -o /dev/null -s "$line" -w "%{time_total}\n" &
    count=$((count+1))
    (( count % 3 == 0 )) && { wait; echo "process wait"; } # wait for 3 urls
done < <(head -n 10 urls.txt)
echo "before wait"
wait
echo "after wait"
```

Answer (score 0):

> why it's happening?

Because you run the processes in the subshell, the parent process can't wait for them.

```
$ echo | { echo subshell; sleep 100 & }
$ wait  # exits immiedately
$
```

Call wait from the same process the background processes were spawned:

```
someotherthing | {
   while someotherthing; do
      something &
   done
   wait  # will wait for something
}
```

> And how to fix this?

I recommend not to use a crude `while read` loop and use different approach using some tool. Use GNU `xargs` with `-P` option to run 3 processes concurently:

```
head -n 10 urls.txt | xargs -P3 -n1 -d '\n' curl -o /dev/null -w "%{time_total}\n" -s
```

But you could just use move `wait` into the subshell as above, or make the `while loop` to be executed in the parent shell alternatively.

Comment: I definitely agree that using `xargs -P3` is the better way to run a given number of processes in the background. (That said, if we were interpreting the question as being about how to do that best, there are plenty of candidates it could be closed as duplicative of).